# Hosted Site Not using CSS/JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have created a site, running it locally using XAMPP as i developed it, and it runs perfectly when local.

However i tested it when hosted and the CSS & JQuery (Google library) do not work at all.

The CSS tags use the standard:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/css.css">
```

Is there a reason this wouldnt work when live? But surely this has nothing to do with why JQuery doesnt work either?

I dont feel comfortable leaving it live when it doesnt work, so im sorry i cannot give you a live version to view.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Where is your CSS file relative to your HTML file?

Comment: What does your implementation to jQuery look like?

Comment: Do you get a 404 error when you browse to http://<yoursite>/css/css.css ? Where does your CSS directory exist on the hosted server?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the console for errors?

Answer (score 4):

Do check with Inspector if the CSS and JS files are loaded correctly when you go live — do note that the first slash in front of the URL means you're referencing the root URL of the live site. Are the directory structures of the local and live site different?

Also, you can try loading the external files using the absolute URL, like http://domain.tld/css/css.css (double check if the file exists, or loadable). If it works, then it's your relative URL path that is not working.

[Edit]: For the sake of completeness, this is how relative URL paths work:

- `/<fileName>.<fileExtension>` will point to the file at the root directory
- `./<fileName>.<fileExtension>` will point to the file in the same directory as the current page
- `../<fileName>.<fileExtension>` will point to the file in the directory one level above, relative to the current directory

Comment: On the host server the site is in a folder called 'public_html' off the root. But even when i changed the css tag (/public_html/css/css.css) the still wouldnt work.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the CSS file directly, by typing the entire URL in the URL bar of your browser? `/public_html/` is the root folder, and it is reference as the first slash in the url.

Comment: When i browse for the css directly (domain.com/css/css.css) it shows me the content of the css file as a basic text document.

Comment: That should be right. What happens when you refer to the CSS file with the absolute URL? Does it get loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have actually uploded CSS files into `/css/` folder. (Obviously `/css/` folder should be present on your server)

Make sure you can access you CSS files from the web: eg if you go here`http://yourdomain.com/css/css.ss` you should see the contents of you CSS file.

if you can see the contents of your file here: `http://yourdomain.com/css/css.css`

then try this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yourdomain.com/css/css.css">`

And as @Terry already mentioned check the paths.

Comment: Using your method worked:

    <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="http://yourdomain.com/css/css.css>



However JQuery does not still work, and what i didnt notice  that was missing in the first place which still doesnt work is that a div is not being displayed.

Comment: Changing JQuery library location made no change.

Comment: Can you post a link to that site.